# Arduino WaveHC collecting filenames

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, arduino

For a little Arduino-Fun-project using WaveHC, I would like to store the filenames on the SD-card in a 2-dimensional char-array.

Don't have enough C-knowledge though.

I tried:

```
...
FatReader root;
FatVolume vol;
dir_t dirBuf;
char **allFilenames;
...

//get number of files
int fileCount = 0;

while(root.readDir(dirBuf) > 0) {

    fileCount++;
}

//prepare array, filenames will always be 8 + 1 
allFilenames = malloc(fileCount * sizeof(char[9]));
```

Now if fileCount gets bigger then say 15, it seems to overflow heavily when assigning filenames and trying to access them.

So my questions are
1. is the malloc()-statement correct?
2. if yes, my method will not work because of memory-limitations, correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your malloc is incorrect. fileCount * sizeof(char[9]) is equal to fileCount * 9, which is not a size you want to use for a double char pointer. Your double char pointer should point to a segment of data which is a multiple of sizeof(char*), not a multiple of 9.

Try something like:

```
allFilenames = malloc(fileCount * sizeof(char*));
for(int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
    allFilenames[i] = malloc(9);
}
```

EDIT:
The main problem is that you only allocate memory to the double pointer. Since the double pointer points to other pointers, you need to allocate memory for those pointers as well.

You could also declare your allFilenames variable as a pointer to array instead, in which case you will only need one malloc since you only use one pointer. Like this:

```
char (*allFilenames)[9];
```

If you do this your malloc is correct as it is, though you could change sizeof(char[9]) to 9 since they are always equal.

Comment: The allFilenames array seems correct with your first suggestion, but strange things happen. First it did not work if I put anything into the array but a 0. Now the array gets filled correctly with about half the filenames, without any assignment - just looping over them and having written `allFilenames[actFile] = (char*) malloc(9);` ??? (I forgot the needed cast in the original question).
Maybe it's an Arduino problem with uploading changed code all the time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know very much about Arduino so can't help with any problems related to that. The examples in my post should allocate the memory correctly at least.

Comment: Yes, going to accept the answer since its technically correct. I have now put the filename into a temporary variable and assigned the array-field to that variable. Now it doesn't print any garbage anymore, but only the last read filename, but that should be resolvable.